# A product of smooth manifolds together with one smooth manifold with boundary is a smooth manifold with boundary

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $M_1, \dots M_k$ are smooth manifolds and $N$ is a smooth manifold with boundary. Then how do I see that  $M_1 \times \dots \times M_k \times N$ is a smooth manifold with boundary, and$$\partial(M_1 \times \dots \times M_k \times N) = M_1 \times \dots \times M_k \times \partial N?$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the simpler result that finite products of smooth (boundaryless) manifolds are smooth manifolds, your problem can be reduced to the case where $k=1$.

Now, given any point $\left(x,y\right) \in M_{1} \times N$, there exists a chart $\left(U,\phi\right)$ at $x$ in the atlas of $M_{1}$ and a chart $\left(V,\psi\right)$ at $y$ in the atlas of $N$. Now, $U \times V$ is a neighborhood of $\left(x,y\right)$ in the product topology, and the map $\phi \times \psi$ is a homeomorphism from $U\times V$ to $\mathbb{R}^{m} \times \mathbb{H}^{n}$. Noting that $\mathbb{H}^{n} := \left\{\left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{n} | x_{n} \geq 0\right\}$, we have $\mathbb{R}^{m} \times \mathbb{H}^{n} = \mathbb{H}^{m+n}$. Use this to show that $M_{1} \times N$ is a manifold with boundary.

For the second part, given any point $\left(x,y\right)$, either $y \in \partial N$ (that is, $\psi\left(y\right) \in \partial \mathbb{H}^{n}$) or $y \notin \partial N$ (that is, $\psi\left(y\right) \notin \partial \mathbb{H}^{n}$. Now, $\partial \mathbb{H}^{n} := \left\{\left(x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{n} | x_{n} = 0\right\}$. Thus, $\partial \left(\mathbb{R}^{m} \times \mathbb{H}^{n}\right) = \mathbb{R}^{m} \times \partial \mathbb{H}^{n}$. Use this to show that $\partial M_{1} \times N = M_{1} \times \partial N$.

Comment: "Using the simpler result that the countable product of smooth (boundaryless) manifolds is a smooth manifold" surely you mean finite product.

Comment: Yes, I'll make the edit. I suppose you can't talk about countable products if you're taking charts to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ as the definition.

Answer (score 0):

First we prove $M_1 \times ... \times M_k \times N$ is a manifold with boundary.
Given any point $p = (x_1,...,x_k,y) \in M_1 \times ... \times M_k \times N$ we can choose a coordinate chart $(U_i,\varphi_i)$ for each $M_i$ such that $x_i \in U_i$ and $(V,\psi)$ for $N$ such that $y\in V$. Then see that:
\begin{equation*}
    \varphi_1 \times ... \times \varphi_k \times \psi: U_1 \times .... \times U_k \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n_1} \times .... \times \mathbb{R}^{n_k} \times \mathbb{H}^n 
\end{equation*}
is a homeomorphism onto its image and is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n_1} \times .... \times \mathbb{R}^{n_k} \times \mathbb{H}^n$ and hence is a manifold with boundary.
For the second part, observe that by definition a point $p = (x_1,...,x_k,y) \in \partial(M_1 \times ... \times M_k \times N)$ if it is in a boundary chart, that is, $p \in U_1 \times .... \times U_k \times V $ such that  $(\varphi_1 \times ... \times \varphi_k \times \psi)( U_1 \times .... \times U_k \times V) \cap \partial (\mathbb{R}^{n_1} \times .... \times \mathbb{R}^{n_k} \times \mathbb{H}^n) \neq \emptyset$. Then looking at this component-wise we can see that it says $\psi(V) \cap \partial \mathbb{H}^n \neq \emptyset$. It means that $p \in M_1 \times ... \times M_n \times \partial N$. So, we have one side inclusion, that $ \partial(M_1 \times ... \times M_k \times N) \subseteq  M_1 \times ... \times M_k \times \partial N  $, and other side can be done by reversing the reasoning. Like, if we pick a point $p \in  M_1 \times ... \times M_k \times \partial N$, then it means that $\psi(V) \cap \mathbb{H}^n \neq \emptyset$. Then looking component-wise it means that:$(\varphi_1 \times ... \times \varphi_k \times \psi)( U_1 \times .... \times U_k \times V) \cap \partial (\mathbb{R}^{n_1} \times .... \times \mathbb{R}^{n_k} \times \mathbb{H}^n) \neq \emptyset$.(Here we need to be more precise, we know that since $\mathbb{R}^{n_i}$ are manifolds without boundary(or with boundary but boundary is empty set), and we also know that $\varphi(U_i)$ is an open set inside $\mathbb{R}^{n_i}$, and hence they have non-empty intersections at all components and in particular in last component as well. Therefore, we can say product has also non-empty intersection.) Hence again $p \in \partial(M_1 \times ... \times M_k \times N)$. And hence we have:$M_1 \times ... \times M_k \times \partial N  \subseteq  \partial(M_1 \times ... \times M_k \times N)$. It finally gives us:
\begin{equation*}
    M_1 \times ... \times M_k \times \partial N  =  \partial(M_1 \times ... \times M_k \times N)
\end{equation*}