# Why for Cartesian product of smooth manifolds we have $Int(M \times N) = M \times Int N $?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

We note that while the Cartesian product of smooth manifolds is a smooth manifold; since in $M  \times N$ we consider the maximal
atlas that contains all coordinate systems of the form $(U_{\alpha} \times V_{\beta}, \phi_{\alpha}  \times \psi_{\beta})$, where
$(U_{\alpha}, \phi_{\alpha})$ and $(V_{\beta}, \psi_{\beta})$ are smooth coordinate systems of $M$ and $N$, respectively , But the Cartesian product of two manifolds with boundary is not a manifold with boundary.

On the other hand, the Cartesian product of manifolds
such that only one of which has boundary, is a manifold with boundary with boundary $\partial (M \times N) = M \times  \partial N$ and interior $Int(M \times  N) = M \times  Int N $. (why?)

> > > Sorry, I found a proof of this observation here [linked to the result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1557936/a-product-of-smooth-manifolds-together-with-one-smooth-manifold-with-boundary-is/1557968)

But still I need to know why we have $Int(M \times  N) = M \times  Int N $?

Can someone help me to see why this is the case here?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about the obvious special cases, namely: Why is $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ a manifold? Why is $\mathbb{R} \times [0,1]$ a manifold with boundary but not a manifold? Why is $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ not a manifold with boundary?

Comment: I've heard a notion of a *manifold with corners* for things like $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$.

Comment: @LeeMosher: actually $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ is a **topological** manifold with boundary. (It's homeomorphic to the unit disk.)

Comment: Yes, but I was going by the tag "smooth-manifolds" --- which matches the presuppositions of the question --- and in that category it is not a manifold-with-boundary. @RobArthan

Comment: @LeeMosher: I don't really see what you mean (unless you take smooth manifolds to be defined as subspaces of $\Bbb{R}^n$ for some $n$ with a smooth structure that is smooth with respect to the standard metric on $\Bbb{R}^n$). Conclusion: the OP needs to give more context rather than leave it to us to guess the context.

Comment: @LeeMosher Many thanks! I changed the question a bit. I also found a proof for boundary case. Now I need to know the case for interior?

Comment: @RobArthan Many thanks! I changed the question a bit. I also found a proof for boundary case. Now I need to know the case for interior?

Comment: In my own mind, I was going by the definition of smooth manifolds as locally modeled on $\mathbb{R}^n$ or its closed half-space, with smooth overlaps. But, as you suggest, I didn't want to prejudice the question by making assumptions about the context, so that's why I asked the OP about those three examples. @RobArthan